# Gitlab commands not working through IIS web application

Tags: c#, iis, gitlab

I have a requirement to clone gitlab project and get commit details through c# application. I am able to execute all gitlab commands such as clone, pull, fetch, show etc in my machine through command line and mvc application. Same commands are not working when application in deployed on IIS server. clone and pull commands are not working, they are simply hanged and no output is produced.  Can someone tell me what settings are required to be done to make gitlab commands work through web application. I have spent 4 days on this issue and still not able to resolve.My c# code is below

```
            compiler.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
            compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = "git pull";
            compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            compiler.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = local_repository;
            compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            compiler.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            compiler.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            compiler.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
            compiler.Start();
            try
            {

                compiler.WaitForExit();
                exitcode = compiler.ExitCode;
            }


   git clone "my_gitlab_url"
   git pull
```

Comment: strange thing is gitlab commands are working in server command line locally but not working when application is deployed.

Comment: Are you running these commands via C# code? Can you share the code which runs the command?

Comment: yes it is c# code. Code works fine in my local.

Comment: can you share the relevant code?

Comment: just added my code in the question

Comment: can u please check it now.  I am trying to execute git pull and git clone commands through c# code

Comment: First thing I would think is that the server isn't going to let you run an executable in system32. That would be just a stupidly huge security risk to allow that. It would run fine locally for you testing since it's probably running under your credentials. You might try ensuring the app pool can run 32-bit applications since this is in system32. I would strongly, strongly, strongly recommend you don't give the permissions necessary to allow the web application to run files in the windows directory. Instead, look for a native component that allows for git commands from C#.

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick we execute most of the command line commands though c# code in this manner. Do you think i should try through powershell script?